# Elastic Search Query Priority

Tags: elasticsearch, boost, elasticsearch-query

If we search for "Padma Priya" and is there any exact match then we need to show that result first but what happening is It's showing "Padma" posts first only because of keyword density and weightage.

If there is no "Padma Priya" then we want to show "Padma" results and "Priya" Results as per keyword density and weightage.

If we found both "Padma Priya" Keyword in Text and the URL then we need to give high priority to URL then Title after that page content.

This is my query:

```
{
            searchBody = {
                "from" : 0,
                "size" : size,
                "query": {
                    "bool": {
                        "should" : [
                            {
                              "match": {
                                "location": {
                                  "query": q,
                                  // "boost": 5
                                }
                              }
                            },
                            {
                              "match": {
                                "title": {
                                  "query": q,
                                  "boost": 5
                                }
                              }
                            }
                            ,
                            {
                              "match": {
                                "description": {
                                  "query": q
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          ]
                    }
                }
            };
```

}

Comment: @can you please add your index mapping, sample docs, your search query so that I can use that to provide the correct query?

Answer (score 1):

As shown in [ES boost doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-boost.html) first query, you can see how to give more boost/priority to your `title` fields than the page content which is very common use-case.

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "title": {
        "type": "text",
        "boost": 2 ---> note this same text will get twice priority/boost if found in title field.
      },
      "content": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

for your first use-case of **If we search for "Padma Priya" and is there any exact match**, you need to combine the phrase query with your existing query to get the result at the top.

**Concept will be clear by below example:**

Index sample doc, index will be created automatically.

```
{
   "title" : "Padma is the author of post",
   "content" : "If we search for Padma and is there any exact match then we need to show that result first but what happening is It's showing Padma posts first only because of keyword density and weightage."
}
```

Index another doc which has `padam priya` as a phrase:

```
{
   "title" : "Padma Priya",
   "content" : "If we search for Padma and is there any exact match then we need to show that result first but what happening is It's showing Padma posts first only because of keyword density and weightage."
}
```

**Search query**

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "multi_match": {
                        "query": "Padma Priya",
                        "fields": [
                            "title^3", --> this will give 3X priority of title field
                            "content"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match_phrase": {
                        "title": "Padma Priya"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**And search result**

```
 "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "indexboost",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 1.8336343, // note high score for exact match
                "_source": {
                    "title": "Padma Priya",
                    "content": "If we search for Padma and is there any exact match then we need to show that result first but what happening is It's showing Padma posts first only because of keyword density and weightage."
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "indexboost",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 0.9081677,
                "_source": {
                    "title": "Padma is the author of post",
                    "content": "If we search for Padma and is there any exact match then we need to show that result first but what happening is It's showing Padma posts first only because of keyword density and weightage."
                }
            }
        ]
```

Comment: I have shared my script, can you please help

Comment: @PadmaLakshmi your query is just a example I believe and what is the issue you are having with that? did you get a chance to try the complete example which I provided in my answer :)

Comment: tried it but it's not working, can we hire you personally?